# "Any integrable r.v can be viewed as an element of a space that is a bit like Lp for p>1"

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

(Sorry in advance if this question was asked elsewhere in a different form, and/or if it is trivial.)

In the proof of Lemma 4.5 of "Stochastic calculus and financial applications" (Steele 2001) the following fact is used with $f(x) = P(|Z| \geq x)$ where $E[|Z|]<\infty$: (paraphrasing,)

> if $f: R_+ \to R_+$ is non-negative, decreasing and integrable, and $f(0)=1$, then we can find a function $a$ such that $a(x) \geq 1$, $a$ increases to $+\infty$, and
> $$\int_0^\infty a(x) f(x) dx < \infty.$$

1. Is my above statement true, or is there some other important feature of $f(x) = P(|Z| \geq x)$ that I forgot?
2. How does one show that statement?
3. Does the statement remain true if we remove some of the assumptions on $f$?

My attempt at a proof: Letting such an $f$ and supposing the contrary, if we construct a sequence $a_n$ satisfying the conditions and such that $a_n \to 1$ point-wise, and if we can ensure $\int_0^\infty \lim_n (f \cdot a_n) = \lim_n \int_0^\infty (f \cdot a_n)$, then we can conclude $\int_0^\infty f = \infty$, a contradiction. But I didn't manage to construct such a sequence $a_n$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assumption that $f(0)=1$ is not needed.

Let $T(x):=\int_x^\infty f(u)\,du$. $\;$ Note that $$S(x):=2T(0)-2\sqrt{T(x)T(0)}$$ satisfies
$$S'(x)=\frac{f(x)\sqrt{T(0)}}{\sqrt{T(x)}} \,,$$
so
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)\sqrt{T(0)}}{\sqrt{T(x)}}\,dx=S(x)|_0^\infty =2{T(0)}\,.$$
Thus you can take $$a(x):=\frac{\sqrt{T(0)}}{\sqrt{T(x)}} \,.$$

**Remark:** Conversely, if $g > 0$ is not integrable, then there exists $b(x) \downarrow 0$ such that $g(x)b(x)$ is still not integrable.
Indeed, let $G(x)=\int_0^x g(u) \,du $. Then  $b(x)=1/G(x)$  will do, because $\frac{d}{dx} \log G=g/G$.

Comment: I guess the assumption that $f$ is decreasing isn't needed either.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge
 Right.